# jquery: how to prevent downbutton to scroll down parent div if child div is on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Im working on auto complete search box. everything is working fine but when user press down key to scroll through search results, the parent div is also scrolling down. How can i prevent the parent div from scrolling if child div or ul is focused.

```
    <div id="parentdiv">
        <div id="autoholder" tabindex='1'>
            <ui class="autodropdown"> 
                 // result is populated here using ajax 
                 // for example
                 //<li>first result</li>
                 //<li>second result </li> and so on....
            </ui>   
        </div>
    </div>
```

for js i have

```
$(window).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 40) {
        $('#autoholder').focus();
        if ($('ul.autodropdown li').hasClass('active')) {
            var h = $('ul.autodropdown li.active').index();
            $("ul.autodropdown li:eq(" + h + ")").removeClass('active');
            next = $("ul.autodropdown li:eq(" + h + ")").next();

        } else {
            $("ul.autodropdown li:eq(0)").addClass('active');
        }
    } else if (e.which === 13) {
        alert($('ul.autodropdown li.active').text());
    }
});
```

when the user  press downbutton while #autoholder is focused, I just want the user to go down only in the #autoholder div not the parent div or the body.

thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try e.preventDefault()?

Comment: Unless you're doing something really different here, the `autocomplete` `jQuery UI` widget should do all this work by design.

Comment: If you're not using the widget, add some code to your script to check for the `event` `target` and decide whether to scroll.

Comment: <ui class="autodropdown">  should be <ul class="autodropdown">

Comment: @MelanciaUK, i was thinking of using the autocomplete widget from jquery UI but the result that is populated by ajax is not only text. it also included pictures. Thus adjusting the widget was too complicated for me so i decided to code my own autocomelete.  Thank you for you time and advice though.

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst thank you so much. I played around with e.preventDefault() and it worked. Also thank you for pointing the typo i did with ul. I wouldnt have caught it.

Comment: I've added my comment as answer. Please mark my answer as correct for people with the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems;

You have a small typo: instead of  you are using

You don't prevent the default event-behaviour. Try something like this:

```
e.preventDefault();
```